# console.log prints function definition, along with function expected output

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log, prototype-programming

I have the following code written:

```
Array.prototype.toMyString = function() {
    var _new_line_str = '';
    for(var j in this) {
        (this.length-1) != j 
            ? _new_line_str += this[j]+';' 
            : _new_line_str += this[j];
    }
    return _new_line_str;
};
```

The above method is called using the following code:

```
_new_line_str = line_arr.toMyString();
console.log(_new_line_str);
```

But using **console.log(_new_line_str);** written above prints the result followed by function definition for **toMyString()** function, and not the only result from it.

```
Output:
this;is;a;result;of;above;code;;;;23function() {
    var _new_line_str = '';
    for(var j in this) {
        (this.length-1) != j 
            ? _new_line_str += this[j]+';' 
            : _new_line_str += this[j];
    }
    return _new_line_str;
};
```

Comment: Practically there is a native function for what you're trying to achieve `line_arr.join(';')`

Comment: @Kirill Slatin: The function mentioned above is a demo for what I am trying to achieve. This is not the exact implementation. The real implementation includes several conditions and methodologies within this operation, and this is used all over my application over arrays. Though thumbs up for the tip. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `for in` to iterate over elements of an array, you're listing the object properties, including the inherited ones (among them the function you added).

Change

```
for(var j in this) {
```

to

```
for(var j=0; j<this.length; j++) {
```

From the MDN, [Array iteration and for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in):

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
>   are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no
>   guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular
>   order and **it will return all enumerable properties, including those
>   with non–integer names and those that are inherited**.

Note also that it's considered bad practice to add unexpected functions to objects you don't own (especially native ones) and that this functions looks useless : you can get the same result using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with `line_arr.join(";")`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also for the tip of using line_arr.join(";"), this is not the exact implementation of my method, this is a demo, originally this includes some conditions and methodologies for this, also this is used all over my application, then I guess this approach is helpful. Please suggest, if there is any other solution to this.

Comment: @HVT7 Hard to tell without more information but I usually prefer to combine `map` and `join` rather than to use a `for` loop. For example, type this in your console: `["A", 3, {}].map(function(v, k){ return k+":"+v+"("+typeof v+")" }).join(";")`.